# DRY with methods as arguments

Tags: java, dry

I've ended up with a couple of methods in several classes that follow the same patterns (it's always a bunch of those methods within each class):

```
private void updateFoo() {
    String newFoo = fooTextField.getText();
    if (!newFoo.equals(record.getFoo())) {
        // "record" stays the same for all methods of this pattern.
        record.setFoo(newFoo);
        record = DATABASE.save(record);
    }
}
```

I can't seem to make this generic as there doesn't seem to be a way to pass a reference to a variable, like `void f(int *outFoo) { *outFoo = 42; }` in C.

Ideally, I'd like to have something like:

```
private void update(JTextField textField, ? getter, ? setter) {
    String newFoo = textField.getText();
    if (!newFoo.equals(getter())) {
        // "record" stays the same for all methods of this pattern.
        setter(newFoo);
        record = DATABASE.save(record);
    }
}
```

so that in the end, I can do something like (pseudo-code):

```
update(fooTextField, &record.getFoo, &record.setFoo);
```

Given the lack of closures in Java, the next best thing I can think of is an interface that "maps" the necessary method calls but this tends to need even more text to type than simply copying those methods. Is there an elegant way to solve this?

Comment: You can use constructs like Functions http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained

Comment: @AntonBessonov: Correct me if I'm wrong, but these are merely function objects. As I wrote, I'd end up writing more text using these than by copying my short methods.

Comment: You cannot pass methods in Java < 8. Even in Java 8 there is just syntactic sugar; on the client side you would still receive an interface with a single method - an SMI.

Comment: The fundamental problem is like you said, Java <=7's lack of closures. This is just a limitation of the language and there isn't a better way. If you want to be DRY, you have to accept the boilerplate. Basically, you either have to repeat yourself or use a lot of boilerplate to implement anonymous classes as @AntonBesseonov suggested. Java 8 will introduce lambdas though :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments closures in Java 8 will help here.

Something that can be done with current Java is to pass in String objects for the method names, using reflection to call the methods and then return the newFoo. There is a better way though which involves no generics and no reflection:

```
String update(JTextField textField, String oldFoo) {
    String newFoo = textField.getText();
    if (!newFoo.equals(oldFoo)) {
        record = DATABASE.save(record);
    }
    return newFoo;
}
```

Then each time you use the code it just becomes:

```
setter(update(textField, getter()));
```

For example:

```
setName(update(textFieldName, getName()));
```

Which has removed most of your DRY concerns. The only real drawback is the fact that the setter gets called even on no change, I'd expect the setter to be pretty lightweight though so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: The setter has to be called before calling `save` so this doesn't work, but idea itself is useful. Thanks.

Comment: Ahh. In that case you would need to move the save code into the setter, but you end up with boiler plate in every setter that way so really things get messy whatever you do.